# html fullscreen: Disable status bar on android

Tags: android, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

I've noticed after upgrading to Android 8, the status bar is not hidden on Chrome anymore with `html5` fullscreen. Is there a way to hide this? This wasn't the case with previous Android versions.

**Chrome:** 64.0.3282.137

**OS:** Android 8.0.0, HTC 10 Build/OPR1.170623.0267

```
$([fullscreenButton, fullscreenSideButton]).on('click', function(){
    self.goFullScreen();
});
goFullScreen: function(){
    var self = this;
    var viewel = document.getElementById('viewer-container');
    if(viewel.requestFullscreen) {
        viewel.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (viewel.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        viewel.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (viewel.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        viewel.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (viewel.msRequestFullscreen) {
        viewel.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
},
```

[image: Screenshot]